# How to change the appearance of a MenuFlyout in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, user-interface, windows-phone-8.1

I read mostly all of this article, but I just can't find out how I can change e.g. the entrance theme transition of the MenuFlyout, like it appears in the calender app. There is something like a horizontal turn instead of the default Animation of the MenuFlyout.

[image: Windows phone calender app]

---

```
<MenuFlyout>
   <MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
       <Style...../>
   </MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
   <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Test"/>
</MenuFlyout>
```

---

C#:

```
 MenuFlyout mf = (MenuFlyout)this.Resources["AddButtonFlyout"];
 mf.Placement = FlyoutPlacementMode.Bottom;
 mf.ShowAt(this.CommandBar);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MenuFlyout has a standard Style which is set for TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter" and can be found in ..\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.1\Include\abi\Xaml\Design\generic.xaml (I will not copy/paste here because it's quite long). This Style defines a ControlTemplate which you can modify to set how the MenuFlyout behaves when it changes to BottomPortrait VisualState.

From what I can see in the Calendar app, the MenuFlyout kind of flips when you open it. In predefined Style it first displays the top border and then draws the rest from top to bottom.

So, first of all you need to copy the whole Style to your resources. Then you need to find the BottomPortrait VisualState and clear everything from the Storyboard to be able to define your own from scratch.

I'll use a PlaneProjection class - it give that sort of a 3D effect which is what you're looking for. I added it to the CenterBorder Border element and set the default value to -90. I set it to -90 because that means it's perpendicular to the screen and the MenuFlyout is therefore not visible when first shown.

```
// ... rest of the code
<Border x:Name="CenterBorder" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Background}">
    <Border.Projection>
        <PlaneProjection RotationX="-90"/>
    </Border.Projection>
// ... rest of the code
```

The next (and final) step is to define the new Storyboard in BottomPortrait VisualState as mentioned earlier - and it's really simple:

```
// ... rest of the code
<VisualState x:Name="BottomPortrait">
    <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.18" 
                         To="0" 
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationX)" 
                         Storyboard.TargetName="CenterBorder" />
     </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
// ... rest of the code
```

It just animates the Border from -90 to 0 degrees in very short period of time, which makes it go from invisible to visible with a nice flip animation, which is what you're looking for.

The Style (with irrelevant parts omitted for brevity - you should still have them!):

```
<Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
    <!-- OTHER PROPERTY SETTERS -->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                <Border x:Name="OuterBorder" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PlacementStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="None" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="TopPortrait">
                                <!-- TOP PORTRAIT STORYBOARD -->
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="BottomPortrait">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.18" 
                                                     To="0" 
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationX)" 
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="CenterBorder" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="LeftLandscape">
                                <!-- LEFT LANDSCAPE STORYBOARD -->
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="RightLandscape">
                                <!-- RIGHT LANDSCAPE STORYBOARD -->
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="OuterScaleTransform" />
                    </Border.RenderTransform>
                    <Border x:Name="CenterBorder" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Border.Projection>
                            <PlaneProjection RotationX="-90"/>
                        </Border.Projection>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="InnerBorder" FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                                <ScaleTransform x:Name="InnerScaleTransform" />
                            </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

EDIT:

Showing the MenuFlyout is best done on a frame.

```
MenuFlyout mf = (MenuFlyout)this.Resources["AddButtonFlyout"];
mf.Placement = FlyoutPlacementMode.Bottom;

Frame fr = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
mf.ShowAt(fr);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm pretty sure I did something wrong, because with this style nothing appears, 
just the rest of the ui zooms out a little.
I edited my question to show what I tried.

Comment: @Cort3vl Did you set the MenuFlyout placement to FlyoutPlacementMode.Bottom?

Comment: @Cort3vl You're showing the AddButtonFlyout, but the MenuFlyout which you attached in your question doesn't have that Key.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was just a mistake here in the question. I tried to shorten it. In my actual code in Visual Studio the MenuFlyout has the key 'AddButtonFlyout'.

Comment: @Cort3vl Try showing it on a current frame, and not CommandBar. I've edited my answer.

Comment: It works! Showing the MenuFlyout on the Frame was the solution. Thank you!

Comment: There seems to be still a problem. Since I'm showing the MenuFlyout on the Frame, the app crashes after I click on a MenuFlyoutItem.
"Das Programm "[2352] wurde mit Code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation' beendet."

Comment: @Cort3vl Nope, not on my device. What do you do in Click event handler?

Comment: Now it's always the error: "System.IO.FileNotFoundExeception". This error only occurs if I'm showing it on a Frame. 
I'm calling Frame.Navigate(typeof(AnyPage));